# how to keep an exact part of data and then see how many times/where it is repeated?

Tags: r

I am struggling to find a way to

```
Variable 1                        Variable 2                 Varibale 3
propo.MO.665.550002name     propo.NO.665.240307600name     preg.NM.240242141220.name
isoc.MO.40641112706.A08.    bo.NO.550002402421312          sal.NM.5500024024214122006604
X....ch.MO.064111.name      X....ch.NO.644111.name         X....ch.NM.641.64064111.name
bo.MO.550002402421312       sene.NO.0.644.59.F04.name      ka.NM.21906560.G04.name
retro.MO.02402421312190     ne.NO.1.64064111207.name       mev.NM.271707292.F12.name
sal.MO.5500024024216604     dimen.NO.4006560.C10.name      acetya.NM.65111406.F05.name
Prest.MO.207028.E07.name    ricini.NO.3041107269.H04.name   amyl.NM.3111306.C03.name
ka.MO.213121.G04.name       ka.NO.2131560.G04.name          ka.NM.121906560.G04.name
```

First I want to remove whatever is after MO. or NO. or NM. in each column respectively.

so my output will look like this

```
Variable 1                        Variable 2                 Varibale 3
    propo.MO.                    propo.NO.                   preg.NM.
    isoc.MO.                     bo.NO.                      sal.NM.
    X....ch.MO.                  X....ch.NO.                 X....ch.NM.
    bo.MO.                       sene.NO.                    ka.NM.
    retro.MO.                    ne.NO.                      mev.NM.
    sal.MO.                      dimen.NO.                   acetya.NM.
    Prest.MO.                    ricini.NO.                  amyl.NM.
    ka.MO.                       ka.NO.                      ka.NM.
```

Then I want to check which one of them is repeated in the three columns and how many times (this comparison should not take into account .MO. , .NO. and .NM.)

for example

```
propo       row 1, column 1 and 2,  
X....ch     row 3, column 1, 2 and 3 
 ka         row 8, column 1, 2 and 3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can loop (`lapply`) through the columns of the dataset ('df1') and remove the part after 'MO.' or 'NO.', or 'NM.' and assign the result back to the same dataset (`df1[] <-`)

```
df1[] <- lapply(df1, function(x) sub('(.*(MO.|NO.|NM.)).*', '\\1', x))
df1
#   Variable.1  Variable.2  Varibale.3
#1   propo.MO.   propo.NO.    preg.NM.
#2    isoc.MO.      bo.NO.     sal.NM.
#3 X....ch.MO. X....ch.NO. X....ch.NM.
#4      bo.MO.    sene.NO.      ka.NM.
#5   retro.MO.      ne.NO.     mev.NM.
#6     sal.MO.   dimen.NO.  acetya.NM.
#7   Prest.MO.  ricini.NO.    amyl.NM.
#8      ka.MO.      ka.NO.      ka.NM.
```

To get the 'row/column' index of the strings without the `.MO|.NO|.NM`, use `sub` again to remove those, and then update it on dataset "df2".

```
df2 <- df1
df2[] <- lapply(df1, function(x) sub('(.*)(.MO|.NO|.NM).*', '\\1', x))

df2
#  Variable.1 Variable.2 Varibale.3
#1      propo      propo       preg
#2       isoc         bo        sal
#3    X....ch    X....ch    X....ch
#4         bo       sene         ka
#5      retro         ne        mev
#6        sal      dimen     acetya
#7      Prest     ricini       amyl
#8         ka         ka         ka
```

If we need to find whether the unique elements are present in each of the columns, one option is `mtabulate`

```
library(qdapTools)
Indx <- mtabulate(df2)
Indx
#          acetya amyl bo dimen isoc ka mev ne preg Prest propo retro ricini
#Variable.1      0    0  1     0    1  1   0  0    0     1     1     1      0
#Variable.2      0    0  1     1    0  1   0  1    0     0     1     0      1
#Varibale.3      1    1  0     0    0  2   1  0    1     0     0     0      0
#           sal sene X....ch
#Variable.1   1    0       1
#Variable.2   0    1       1
#Varibale.3   1    0       1

which(Indx>0, arr.ind=TRUE) #gives the `row/column' index
```

Suppose, if we need it for each row, then

```
v1 <- unique(unlist(df2))
 setNames(lapply(v1,function(x) which(x==df2,arr.ind=TRUE)),v1)
```

For finding the index of rows that don't have duplicate elements

```
 which(apply(df2, 1, function(x) length(unique(x)))==3)
 #[1] 2 4 5 6 7
```

Or

```
 which(!apply(df2, 1, anyDuplicated))
 #[1] 2 4 5 6 7
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get your question.  isn't the `sub` in my solution doing the same thing?

Comment: thanks,  the first part works just fine but the second part hmmm I want to not take into account the .MO. , .NO. and .NM. when we check for their existence in different columns

Comment: @Nemo I removed the `.MO, `.NO`, `.NM` in `df2`

Comment: @Nemo That's why he uses `df2` which is stripped from `.MO|.NO|.NM`

Comment: @Nemo I did remove that one in `df2`.  I think the `mtabulate` answer was not you wanted.  I updated with `v1` and the loop method. Please check

Comment: @akrun thanks! if I want to find those that are not repeated in all 3 columns  what should i do ? however, I accepted your answer which was WoW

Comment: @Nemo Do you need the row index i.e.  2,4,5,6,7?

Comment: @Nemo Try `which(apply(df2, 1, function(x) length(unique(x)))==3)#
[1] 2 4 5 6 7`